# NSDateFormatter Partial Results With NULL Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am parsing an RSS feed and using the NSDateFormatter, the code is as follow:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {

        NSLog(@"CURRENT STRING %@", currentString);
        NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
        NSDate *newDate = [df1 dateFromString:currentString];
        NSLog(@"NEW DATE %@", newDate);     

        }
}
```

Following is the log of CURRENT STRING, that is the input provided to the dateformatter:

[image]

Following image shows the log of output NEW DATE that has some null values in it:

[image]

I have tried many questions on the StackOverflow that says to use NSLocale and other things but they didn't work for me. Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: Are all the dates on the same format? Could you print the strings that fail to parse?

Comment: Are you sure that all elements have the same date format?

Comment: You need to show the input values -- without that your question is meaningless.

Comment: Also make sure you add the locale of the date to the date formatter. Because `EEE` and `MMM` are localized name for the day and month, for example, `monday, 16 september 2013 13:14:56 +0200` will not parse on a phone which language is not set to english.

Comment: And it should be noted that NSDateFormatter does not handle parsing day-of-week very well.  It's best if you trim that from your input and drop it from the format.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I have updated the question with the input values and the output values, please take a look.

Comment: @rckoenes kindly check the updated question and please explain the nslocale thing in the answer with the code. Thanks

Comment: @AJ112: Is it just the screenshot or does `currentString` have some leading whitespace (newline/spaces) from the XML parsing? In that case you should remove (trim) the whitespace.

Comment: It's failing on the 24H format. try `@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"`

Comment: I have answer for you... I will post it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing specific localized date, you should provide the correct localization for those dates.

Also be aware of the 24(`HH`) or 12(`hh`) hour notation:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df1.locale = locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
    [df1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    NSDate *newDate = [df1 dateFromString:currentString];
    NSLog(@"NEW DATE %@", newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

**In RSS, ITS NOT necessary what you see in NSLog is how the string is.**

This is happening because you have whitespaces at the end and \n at the end.

So you need to remove those whitespaces and new line like below.

```
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"myStringCode"]];
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
yourString = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

after doing this, try to format date.